# How to return an array with vlookup

Tags: vba

I have a table

```
date   number
01/14  1324e3
01/15  134d32
01/14  15233t
01/13  1s3634
01/14  133624
```

I need to get a `String` exactly like this `'1324e3','15233t','133624'` , i. e. corresponding   to all dates of `01/14`

---

```
Public Function getString (myDate As Variant) As String
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Set ws2 = This.Workbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

getString = Application.Vlookup(myDate, ws2.Range("A:B"),2,false)
End Function
```

works fine but returns only one value  how can I correct it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are incorrectly pulling data from a SQL database because the format for the date and number columns is not typically standard. For the number column (which I am not sure should be a string or number), you might have issues with numbers like "1234e3" because excel will recognize that as a number instead of a string. The date column will also be converted to the format Date: DD-MMM unless you keep it as a string. Ignoring these issues, the below function should build your string.

Also, Vlookup will only return a single value, so because you want to return all matches, I used a loop.

```
Public Function GetString(myDate As Variant) As String
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, Srow As Long, Erow As Long
Dim BuildString As String
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Srow = 2
Erow = ws2.Cells(2, 1).End(xlDown).Row
BuildString = ""

For i = Srow To Erow
    If ws2.Cells(i, 1) = myDate Then
        If BuildString = "" Then
            BuildString = "'" & ws2.Cells(i, 2) & "'"
        Else
            BuildString = BuildString & ",'" & ws2.Cells(i, 2) & "'"
        End If
    End If
Next i
GetString = BuildString
End Function
```